# Movicon SCADA Report Error of Exception 80070057

Tags: excel, windows

We were using SCADA of Movicon 11.6 along with the Siemens 1200 PLC. Which was working fine since last three years. In last year the system were got formatted and all the softwares got uninstalled. We had the backup files of all programs, so we installed softwares again which we know and afterwards SCADA started working fine& communication with PLC also started. System is with windows 10 32 bit.

But the problem is, Reports are not getting open. Reports are loading, but after loading symbol it is showing 'Exception 80070057'in a popup screen with a title of Report filename.movbas

We are not aware which version of MS were used in the system. What will be cause. Can anyone support?

Comment: Why not you contact with support vendor?

Comment: Vendor also dont have backup/supporting documents for analyse the issue. Since the system was installed 5 years ago.